# Trying to upload to xampp local server with php and it's not working

Tags: php, upload, xampp

It gives me this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\create_event.php

and here is my code

HTML:

```
<form class='reg_event' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <p>Nome do evento:<input type='text' name='n_evento'></input></p><br><br>
    <p>Local do evento:<input type='text' name='l_evento'></input></p><br><br>
    <p>Data do evento:<input type='text' name='d_evento'></input></p><br><br>
    <p>Imagem do evento:<input type='file' name='upload' id='upload'></input></p><br><br>
    <p>Link do evento:<input type='text' name='link_evento'></input></p><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name='submit'></input>
  </form>
```

PHP

```
<?php

include 'dbh.php';

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

  $n_evento = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['n_evento']);
  $l_evento = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['l_evento']);
  $d_evento = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['d_evento']);
  $link_evento = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['link_evento']);
  $file_name = $_FILES['upload']['name'];
  $file_dst = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'event_img/' . $_FILES["file"]["name"];

  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $file_dst);       
  };

}
?>
```

Comment: its `$_FILES["upload"]["name"]` not `$_FILES["file"]["name"]`

Comment: Man, you are the best, i've been looking for that error for so long, but i guess a fresh pair of eyes did the trick :D i so glad for your help, thx man!

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML code seems great. Below PHP code may help you and make sure your upload directory has read/write permission.

```
include 'dbh.php';

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
   $n_evento = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['n_evento']);
   $l_evento = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['l_evento']);
   $d_evento = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['d_evento']);
   $link_evento = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['link_evento']);
   $file_name = $_FILES['upload']['name'];
   $file_dst = 'event_img/' . $file_name;
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $file_dst);       
}
```